# Help interpreting a regular expression

Tags: regex

My skills at interpreting regular expressions are a bit rusty.    Can someone help me with this one?

```
^[V0-9]?\d{2}(\.\d{1,2})?
```

I know the first expressions says that the start of the string begins with the character V or a digit.   But then I have trouble interpreting the rest.  What does the first "?" mean?   I know \d{2} means a two character digit string.   But what does it mean in the context of the preceding "?".    Then is the expression in the parentheses meaning that optionally there is a two digit character string preceded by a "."?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
^[V0-9]?
```

String starts with an optional single character that's either V or a digit (that is, the first `?` pertains to the `[V0-9]`).

```
\d{2}
```

... followed by exactly two digits

```
(\.\d{1,2})?
```

... followed by an optional sequence/subpattern consisting of

```
\.\d{1,2}
```

... a single period (`.`) followed by either 1 or 2 digits.

That means, yes, your interpretation

> Then is the expression in the parentheses meaning that optionally there is a two digit character string preceded by a "."?

is correct (almost).

Comment: And the parens around the subpattern might mean it's captured, depending on the language.